# Trying to create a bash script that adds positive integers taken from input on a single line with spaces

Tags: bash

Im trying to take input from the terminal one line with spaces in between for example input would be something like this.

-1 -1 1

then im trying to take that input and add them together.

the catch is im only supposed to add positive integers so i need to remove the dashes.

I have

```
read Str 
str=( $Str );

arr=${str//-/}




echo "$((${arr[@]/%/+}0))"
```

it seems like its only removing one instance of the dash and not the rest. Not sure which direction to take. Im sure there are multiple solutions.

Any help would be appreciated. I was also thinking maybe an If statement that could remove dashes before adding but not sure how exactly to even begin that.

Comment: when you say you need to remove dashes, does `-1 -1 1` produce `3` (1 + 1 + 1) or `1` (remove negative numbers so only `1` is left)?

Comment: Exactly -1 -1 1 would equal 3. After doing some more research I feel like the method im trying to use may be over simplifying it.

Comment: `${str//-/}` only gets the first element of the `str` array. You'd want to use `arr=("${str[@]//-/}")` to get all of the elements, remove all "-" characters from each of them, and create a new array from the result. (But @paxdiablo's answer makes this unnecessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to accumulate the words one at a time into a sum, removing any optional leading `-` characters, you can do that with something like:

```
read line
((sum = 0))
for num in ${line} ; do
    absnum=${num//-/}
    ((sum += absnum))
done
echo "Sum is" ${sum}
```

Your method of removing leading negative sign is sound, but you don't really need to create an *array* to do the work. You can just iterate over the words as shown.

---

Keep in mind a *real* program should be a little more robust, handling non-numerics and such without falling in a screaming heap. You could do something like this immediately after the assignment to `absnum`:

```
[[ ! "${absnum}" =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*|0$ ]] && echo Bad number ${num} && exit 1
```

This would ensure it was a valid non-negative integer. A sample run follows so you can adjust to whatever test data you'd like to use:

```
pax> echo '3 0 --1 -2 4 40' | bash myscript.bash
Sum is 50
```